# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException- Property must not be null

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, illegalargumentexception, json-query

I am using `SpringBoot1.5.4` Along with that I have `spring-data-mongodb`. Now I am fetching data from a document using Json Query by `@Query` annotation.
I have following implementation:
In `PlayAndEarnProgramRepository`:

```
@Query(value="{'_id' : ?0 , 'vouchers.is_deleted' : ?1, 'vouchers.is_expired' : ?2}",fields="{'vouchers' : 1}")
public List<VouchersPAndE> getActiveVoucherByplayAndEarnId(String id,Boolean isDeleted,Boolean isExpired);
```

Play&Earn model:

```
@Id
@Field(ID)
private String id;

@Field(PLAYANDEARNID)
private String playAndEarnId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

@Field(MERCHANTID)
private String merchantId;

@Field(VOUCHERS)
private List<VouchersPAndE> vouchers;
```

And the call of repoMethod:

```
playAndEarnProgramRepo.getActiveVoucherByplayAndEarnId(program.getId(),false,false);
```

I want to fetch vouchers which are active. But getting following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property must not be null!
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134)
at com.wallet.document.PlayAndEarnProgram_Accessor_71zczn.getProperty(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.DtoInstantiatingConverter$2.doWithPersistentProperty(DtoInstantiatingConverter.java:102)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:346)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.DtoInstantiatingConverter.convert(DtoInstantiatingConverter.java:92)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter.convert(ResultProcessor.java:212)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter$1.convert(ResultProcessor.java:200)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter.convert(ResultProcessor.java:212)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor.processResult(ResultProcessor.java:149)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryExecution$ResultProcessingConverter.convert(MongoQueryExecution.java:444)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryExecution$ResultProcessingExecution.execute(MongoQueryExecution.java:411)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:94)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5009.getActiveVoucherByplayAndEarnId(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong return type, as the error says there is no id field binded with result
You need to bind the result in your Play&Earn model:

`db.PlayAndEarn.find({"_id" : ID , "vouchers.is_deleted" : false, "vouchers.is_expired" : FALSE},{"vouchers" : 1})`

It will show the data format.